# How to install pypy7.3 python3.10 using conda?

Tags: python, pypy

Admittedly I'm new to PyPy, and I need some help.

I have been using PyPy3.9 for a while through guidance from
https://www.pypy.org/posts/2022/11/pypy-and-conda-forge.html

```
 $ conda create -c conda-forge -n my-pypy-env pypy python=3.9
 $ conda activate my-pypy-env
```

The above works great for me, but it doesn't work when I try

```
 $ conda create -c conda-forge -n my-pypy-env pypy python=3.10
 $ conda activate my-pypy-env
```

PyPy.org states that the latest version of PyPy supports Python3.10
https://www.pypy.org/download.html

But I can't get it to work.

I'm not quite sure what to do with the pre-compiled binaries either.
I can run the pypy310.exe, but I'm not sure how to create a conda environment from pre-compiled binaries..

Can someone direct me in the right direction?

I've already tried

```
 $ conda create -c conda-forge -n my-pypy-env pypy python=3.10
 $ conda activate my-pypy-env
```

and was expecting to create a conda environment with pypy3.10.. just like it does for pypy3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conda does not yet support pypy3.10. In [this issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/pypy3.6-feedstock/issues/104) the conclusion was to wait a while for 3.10 since the [3.8/3.9 migration](https://conda-forge.org/status/#pypy38) is stuck without scikit-learn and h5py. I guess it would be helpful if the documentation would mention that only 3.9 is currently supported. If you specifically need 3.10, you could open a new issue on [the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/pypy3.6-feedstock) to express that, we get very little feedback from users who actually want PyPy on conda-forge.

Comment: Thanks for this Mattip, I will provide this feedback in feedstock! Thanks